# Monetizing SE bounties?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

I would like to have a new feature that bounties can also be paid in monetary form e.g. through Paypal?

This would likely increase the competition and quality of answers.

Comment: [One](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25615), [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243404) and [three](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57850) from Meta Stack Exchange. There might be more, but I think you'll get the gist.

Comment: Older related thread: [Integrate bitcoins with MSE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11629/integrate-bitcoins-with-mse)

Comment: Highly relevant is [Shog9's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25621/222340) to the first question linked to by Arthur Fischer.

Comment: To replicate a comment now deleted by our beloved SE employees: What a terrible idea.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To quote [Asaf Karagila](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20752/monetizing-se-bounties#comment79600_20752)

> What  a terrible terrible ...  terrible terrible idea.

(I might have opted for "awful" instead, to squeeze a couple more in there, but the sentiment is the same.)

If you want to pay people to answer your questions, there are already sites which provide this service. So what benefits would it have here?

None that I can see.

In fact, it would completely change the culture of this site.

Instead of being populated by users willing to provide answers for the low, low cost of *the possibility* of a few imaginary internet points, soon you'll see users who hold their answers ransom unless a paid bounty is promised.

You think the pettiness of downvote arguments is bad? Wait until you start to see the arguments that begin over choosing user38613965's answer over user93222358's answer for a paid bounty.

I, for one, would **immediately** leave Stack Exchange were this "feature" implemented.

Answer (score 13):

I don't think this is possible. The Terms of Service guarantee that the service is and remains free, so I think your idea would violate that, even if it is voluntary. (Maybe a moderator of SE official can confirm this?)