# Can I offer cash for an answer to my question?

Tags: feature-request

I want [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4564916/) answered, and I'm willing to pay.  Is there an established way for me to credibly promise payment in a way that will induce an answer?

Has this been done before?  Thank you.

Comment: On this meta: [Monetizing SE bounties?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20752) and [Integrate bitcoins with MSE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11629). If you search a bit, you will certainly find some other related discussion on [meta.se] and on other per-site metas.

Comment: And, as I mentioned, you can have a look at some related discussions on [meta.se] - such as [Pay money to SO for quick support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57850) or [Offering actual money as a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25615) or
[Pay real money to set bounties (another method, not replacing rep method)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243404). (And in each case, you'll find many other related posts among the linked questions.)

Comment: Yes, I get it now - and I wish I could delete this question now but I can't since it has been answered.  Thanks.

Comment: Michael: Just my personal opinion - keeping the question here is useful. If somebody else wants to ask about the same thing, they might find your questions - and from there other related discussion, too. (As a side note - I see from your profile that you're rather active on SO. I would not be surprised if there were on Meta Stack Overflow - but I am not really familiar with that site.)

Comment: This question has many answers already, as you yourself pointed out.  The only reason to leave this up is so people will have a place to kick me with a downvote and smarmy comment for years to come. :D  It's okay I can handle it :D

Comment: Well, I can understand that downvotes are not pleasant. But especially on meta one should not worry about them too much: [On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) (And voting on meta doesn't influence reputation, either.)

Comment: Just in case this is news to you, the non-cash version of this is the [bounty system](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). Once you get at least 50 reputation, you can offer your own reputation as a bounty for your question. Offering a bounty puts your answer in the bountied question tab for a week, and once you get an answer that satisfies you, you can award your reputation to the best answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. You cannot, and you may not, and the moderators may take action if this advice is unheeded.

We do not want to be a "write my thesis" or "do my research" or "solve my homework" site. We are trying to *not be one*.

Any and all attempts to change that will have dire consequences.